# pass props between tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

How can I pass props from one tab to another ? I've tried passProps used in the normal navigation but it doesn't work !

```
this.props.navigator.switchToTab({
  tabIndex: 2,
  // // Pass data on click
  // passProps: {
  //   desc: data
  // }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514633/5461400

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code sample on [react-navigation-docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html)