# Wix react-native-navigation change Tab and push screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

How can I simultaneously switch tab and push screen?
When the button is pressed,
I would like to switch to another tab and push a new screen.
Is it possible?

```
class Example extends Component {
      buttonHandler = () => {
        this.props.navigator.switchToTab({
          tabIndex: 0
        });
        this.props.navigator.push({  // actually this navigator's tabIndex is 0 
          screen: "dc.Examplecreen",
          title: "Exampe", 
          passProps: {
            lesson : this.props
          }    
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for it? I'm having the same need.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch the tab using the following code

```
Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
  bottomTabs: {
    currentTabId: this.props.componentId
  }
});
```

and push using

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: 'example.PushedScreen',
    passProps: {
      text: 'Pushed screen'
    },
    options: {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Pushed screen title'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can make a function combining these 2 codes. Not the best solution i know, but works!

Answer (score 1):

There is no any way to `passProps` with `switchToTab`. also i found in `react-native-navigation` but not get any solution. change tab and push using a global variable.

i am using `react-native-navigation` version `1.1.463`

Change tab `switchToTab`

```
global.isComeFromBooking = true
this.props.navigator.switchToTab({
   tabIndex: 2,
});
```

in tab on index 2 `setOnNavigatorEvent`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent((e) => {
      if (e.id == 'willAppear' && global.isComeFromBooking) {
        this.props.navigator.push({
          screen: 'Reservations',
          title: 'Bookings',
          animated: true,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
          },
          backButtonTitle: '',
        });
        global.isComeFromBooking = false
      }
    });
}
```